# Could not able to connect AWS EC2 API due to error code NoSuchVersion

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, postman

Trying to connect AWS EC2 API for StartInstance from Postman tool.
On AWS document its mentioned to find The API version that the request is written for, expressed in the format YYYY-MM-DD. But i could not able to find relevant API Version for this. Please help.

`{{aws_ec2_base_url}}/?DryRun=True&InstanceId.N=i-0c502addef0c629a6&Action=StartInstances&Version={{Version}}`

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Errors>
        <Error>
            <Code>NoSuchVersion</Code>
            <Message>The requested version (2018-04-02) of service ManagedProxyService does not exist</Message>
        </Error>
    </Errors>
    <RequestID>8cc38cbe-1c3c-4e61-9094-df1246ee75d3</RequestID>
</Response>```
````

Answer (score 0):

As per the latest API documentation version available for ec2 is 2016-11-15

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ec2-api.pdf

Comment: tried but no luck. i think i have not configured request correctly on postman.

Answer (score 0):

this utility helped me to fix the issue.
[nodejs code to build the query string](https://github.com/mhart/aws4)